# Recommended Procedure and Toolset for Server Migration

Tags: windows-server-2003, dell-poweredge, disk-image

Old dell poweredge 2800 with a 2 drive SCSI mirror on an Adaptec 39160 SCSI controller. (2) 146GB UW SCSI HDDs, (1 failed).

New Dell T100 with PERCS300 controller & 3 Drive RAID 5.

Best way to image the old server (Windows SBS2003) onto the new server?  I have some ideas but thought I'd ask the collective for thoughts outside the box.

At this point clean install is not really an option, i'm looking more for a cloning or disc duping that I can use that will support both RAID controllers in the old and the new.
Best option/suggest I'll mark as 'answered'.  Thanks!

[Edit to add: *Without spending $800-$1000 on software.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you'll want something that can backup\image the server and restore it to dissimilar hardware. Here are two products that can do that:

http://www.acronis.com/backup-recovery/server-windows/

http://www.symantec.com/business/backup-exec-system-recovery-server-edition